# Android set height to scrollview not work

Tags: android, scrollview

I use below code for new height to scroll view

But not work

```
viewFindPos = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.Roll);
viewFindPos.getLayoutParams().height = 5000;

// OR : viewFindPos.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 5000));
```

Comment: share more codes, so we can see a better picture of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you get the Layout parameters of the ScrollView, you need to set the LayoutParameters back to the View. Later request the layout, so it's redrawn. Check out this code below, which will help you to understand.

```
LayoutParams params = viewFindPos.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 5000;
viewFindPos.setLayoutParams(params);
viewFindPos.requestLayout();
```

Comment: I'm sure, this will work. the problem with your code probably is that you are trying to set the height before the view is drawn. You need to implement a Global Layout Listener to be able to change the height of the View when it's actually drawn.

Comment: Beside the comment above, you will need to cast your LayoutParams from the right parent View.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

@Override

public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
    {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        ScrollView viewFindPos = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        viewFindPos.getLayoutParams().height = 500;
    }
OR

@Override

protected void onResume()

```
{
    super.onResume(hasFocus);
    ScrollView viewFindPos = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    viewFindPos.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
}
```